# flexible p:menu option of primefaces

Tags: menu, primefaces, contextmenu

I am using Primefaces 3.1.

I have a requirement, where I have to display the menu (like context-menu) based on the user's selection in a particular image in the page.

I have tried the below Tag, and it doesn't have option to render at the mouse cursor.

```
<p:menu type="tiered"  triggerEvent="click"  trigger="idreport" position="dynamic" widgetVar="menuVar"..../>
```

I know that  is one option, but can you please let me know if we can disable right click and allow it to get triggered on "leftClick" ?

Any inputs are appreciated.

thanks,
ravi